# Как поменять расположение сайдбара справа налево

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
/**
 * The sidebar containing the main widget area.
 *
 * @package topshop
 */

if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
    return;
} ?>

<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</aside>><!-- #secondary -->
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете для вашего контейнера в котором контент и сайдбар с помощью флексов поменять расположение:

```
.your-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Либо в шаблоне можете подключить перед контентом